# Expectation involving normal random matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X=(x_{ij})\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ with $p>n$. Assume $x_{ij}$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.

My question is: how to find $E\left(X^{T}(XX^{T})^{-1}X\right)$?

Comment: Intuitively, $X^T(XX^T)^{-1}X$ is just the projection matrix for a random $n$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$, and so, it's expectation should be $\tfrac{n}{p}I$. Of course, that isn't rigorous at all.

Comment: It's a result of A.T. James that the 3 factors in the standard SVD decomposition of your $X$ are independent, and that the $U$ and $V$ parts are uniformly distributed.  From that it's easy to get what you want.